# JW Player crossdomain vulnerability

Tags: flash, jwplayer

I'm using JW Player 6 on my website, but Facebook embedding is not supported, so in the og:video tag I'm still using the old version (5.10).

This version has a vulnerability issue ([source](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/forums/jw-player/setup-issues-and-embedding/24173/jw-player-ignore-crossdomainxml/)): any video can be played on the player hosted on my website (even from other domains).

This behaviour should be prevented using a "crossdomain.xml" file ([source](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28844/crossdomain-file-loading/)), but the player searches for that file on the source domain, not on the domain where the player is hosted, so the file is pretty useless.

How can I set a domain restriction, to prevent the playback from external domains?

If it can't be done, is there any other swf player without vulnerability issues that supports Facebook embedding?

Comment: Since JW5 does indeed have this issue, one other way to secure videos being played would be to restrict this sort of behavior with a .htaccess file on your webserver

Comment: Could you please be more specific? I mean, this is a serious issue, I can't believe it's still unsolved

Comment: Here is something pretty specific about how to do this using .htaccess, but it is a bit technical and the server has to be Apache based - http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/htaccess14.shtml, anyways, I hope this helps.

Comment: No problem, hope that helps.